# Selecting distinct field value based on multiple field values criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_test (id, name, type, value, confirmed) VALUES
        (1, 'Tom', 'good', 'white', 1),
        (2, 'Tom', 'bad', 'red', 1),
        (3, 'Tom', 'fine', 'blue', 1),
        (4, 'Tom',  'ok', 'black', 1),
        (5, 'Alan', 'bad', 'yellow', 0),
        (6, 'Alan', 'good', 'red', 0),
        (7, 'Bob', 'nice', 'white', 0),
        (8, 'Bob', 'ok', 'pink', 0),
        (9, 'Joe', 'good', 'white', 0),
        (10, 'Joe', 'bad', 'pink', 0),
        (11, 'Joe', 'nice', 'red', 0),
        (12, 'Joe', 'fine', 'blue', 0)
```

I would like to select all distinct names which has got type `'ok'` or  any other type (without showing it exactly). so the output shall look like this:

```
name    type    value           confirmed
Tom     ok      black           1
Alan    other   NULL/ /other    0
Bob     ok      pink            0
Joe     other   NULL/ /other    0
```

Is there any way to make it with single query without opration on data on php side?

I tried with subquery

```
SELECT name, type, value, confirmed
  FROM tbl_test
 WHERE type = 'ok'
    OR name IN (SELECT DISTINCT names FROM tbl_test WHERE type != 'ok');
```

but I encounter error even if I try to select only name.
Could you please advise?

Thanks,
Marcin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL` between cases  the `type` cases containing `ok` and `NOT EXISTS` for the cases not containing `ok` types :

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, type, value, confirmed
  FROM tbl_test
 WHERE type = 'ok'
 UNION ALL
SELECT name, 'other', 'NULL/ /other', MAX(confirmed)
  FROM tbl_test t
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM tbl_test WHERE type = 'ok' and name = t.name)
 GROUP BY name
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=634e8ccc6b35a0e983dc622bd0ac0184)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks. I need to digest it, but certainly it does the job. Thanks. One question. Why did you use Max(confirmed)? Why is it better than just 'confirmed'?

Comment: you're welcome @Marcin , since there're multiple rows with confirmed value, we should pick only one row, and we don't know whether one of them would be different than zero. Btw, in that case perhaps choosing MIN(confirmed) would be proper.

Comment: How from the performance perspective UNION ALL compare to LEFT JOIN as presented by @forpas ? I might have several thousands of records to go through with this query couple of times per day.

Comment: There may be more rows with confirmed  = 1, and I would like to see values of them next to the name. For each name they will be the same. Ehther 0 or 1. Will that impact the answer?

Comment: @Marcin I cannot don't know in terms of performance which depends on explain plans of those queries, indexes especially on columns `name` and `type`. Therefore, needed to be tested within the real medium. confirmed values depends on what you need, as I said before you might prefer MIN(confirmed) if you have values with more than than zero, and want to return the zero values. If you have confirmed values equal to 1 along with 0, then the other answer will produce non-distinct rows. I thought aggregation (MIN or MAX)against this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `LEFT` join of the distinct names to the table:

```
select n.name,
       coalesce(t.type, 'other') type,
       coalesce(t.value, 'NULL / other') value,
       coalesce(t.confirmed, 0) confirmed
from (select distinct name from tbl_test) n
left join tbl_test t
on t.name = n.name and t.type = 'ok'
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8yYgCDntLiZrPuC5U6Pohx/3).
Results:

```
| name | type  | value        | confirmed |
| ---- | ----- | ------------ | --------- |
| Tom  | ok    | black        | 1         |
| Bob  | ok    | pink         | 0         |
| Alan | other | NULL / other | 0         |
| Joe  | other | NULL / other | 0         |
```